# How to configure apache for multiple websites e.g. <my_website_name>.localhost

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I want to setup multiple website on my local computers. I want all other computers on my local network to be able to access these.

So I want to map different projects `/www/html/<proj_web_root>`

to `<proj_name>.localhost` so all other computers can access these websites

`<proj_name>.my_ip` and me locally like `<proj_name>.localhost`

How do I configure this per website in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` files and `/etc/hosts`

Answer (score 0):

Personally, i would avoid using the .local domain as a shared group domain. Use something like .dev

In Apache you can use ServerName and ServerAlias directives in a VirtualHost and rewrite rules to achieve your URL routing e.g

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.dev
ServerAlias sub.dev
DocumentRoot /www/html

RewriteRule ^(.*) %{HTTP_HOST}/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

You can also obviously wildcard aliases. Save as dev.conf in /etc/apache/sites-available. To activate things work:

```
a2enmod rewrite
a2ensite dev
```

I am generally not in favour of host hacks but if you insist, it is simply a case of adding stuff to /etc/hosts

One problem of this approach is that you can't wildcard on hostnames. I would advise on using something like [dnsmasq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq) since you can add wildcard entries. In your /etc/dnsmasq.conf you can add something like (change IP address accordingly):

```
address=/.dev/10.0.0.2
```

In all cases cat your /etc/resolv.conf to understand the precedence of your dns resolution